# eclipse project : how to import correctly a class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I'm having this issue while developing in Java using Eclipse as my IDE

I have this class path:

```
src\main\java\com\server\wsname\path\to
```

When i write "package ..." like

```
package com.server.wsname.path.to
```

it gives me this error:

**The declared package "com.server.wsname.path.to" does not match the expected package "main.java.com.server.wsname.path.to"**

but if i write "package ..." like:

```
package main.java.com.server.wsname.path.to
```

everything works fine.

I have the same issue with the import statement, but in this case the error message is **"the import cannot be resolved."**

Am i missing any configuration property in the IDE  related to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project, go on Configure Build Path.. and set 'java' folder as the source location.